# How to open any page on Custom Action(ribbon) with a items metadata in document library?in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, document-library, jsom, custom-actions

here am trying to open new page by clicking on custom action(Ribbon) in document library using sharepoint designer here am able to open page but without passing any meta data of library item. am bit curius about it's feasibility?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You can add a custom action using `CSOM` as below and call a `javascript` function passing the selected item ID when the `custom action` button is clicked.
Have a look at the code below specially the `<CommandUIExtension>` definition- you can specify your `javascript` function in the  `CommandAction` attribute. In your function you can use the javascript `CSOM` to get item details from item ID and pass those as (perhaps query strings) to the page you intend to open.

```
public static void AddCustomListAction(ClientContext clientContext, string listTitle)
{
    string title = "Publish New Items";

    List list = SPHelper.GetList(clientContext, clientContext.Site.RootWeb, listTitle);
    UserCustomActionCollection collUCA = list.UserCustomActions;
    clientContext.Load(collUCA);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    bool found = false;
    UserCustomAction newUCAToRemove = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < collUCA.Count; i++)
    {
        if (collUCA[i].Title == title)
        {
            newUCAToRemove = collUCA[i];
            found = true;
            break;
        }
     }

     if (found)
     {
         newUCAToRemove.DeleteObject();
     }

     // Always replace existing custom action
     UserCustomAction action = collUCA.Add();
     action.Location = "CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView";
     action.Sequence = 1000;
     action.Title = title;
     action.CommandUIExtension = @"<CommandUIExtension><CommandUIDefinitions>"
            + "<CommandUIDefinition Location=\"Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls._children\">"
            + "<Button Id=\"InvokeAction.Button\" TemplateAlias=\"o1\" Command=\"Invoke_Command\" CommandType=\"General\" LabelText=\"Publish new items\" Image32by32=\"_layouts/15/images/placeholder32x32.png\" Image16by16=\"_layouts/15/images/placeholder16x16.png\" />"
            + "</CommandUIDefinition>"
            + "</CommandUIDefinitions>"
            + "<CommandUIHandlers>"
            + "<CommandUIHandler Command =\"Invoke_Command\" CommandAction=\"javascript:clearCache({SelectedItemId});\" />"
            + "</CommandUIHandlers></CommandUIExtension>";

     action.Update();

     clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

}
```

**Useful Links:**
https://lixuan0125.wordpress.com/2014/03/04/add-custom-action-through-csom-with-app/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246019.aspx

Comment: does the same thing is possible with JSOM only?because i want to implement this in sharepoint online,sorry i forgot to mension in question.

Comment: The above code written in CSOM will work for SharePoint online. CSOM, JSOM are both valid choices for O365. Official guidance for adding custom actions in SharePoint online is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/custom-actions-sharepoint-add-in

Comment: so how can i add this CSOM code to so;tion if i suppose to use apps?

Comment: Doing this via an app is one option and the guideline are there on MSDN but you can connect to your sharepoint online site remotely and execute this code to provision a custom action. The related javascript code can be added to the page using a script editor webpart.